# How to Create post call from apex to external system with pass multiple parameters

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest-service

I want to create the rest post Callout from apex to external system(C#)REST API.
but I am Littel bit confused to where to start Coding to consuming Rets API.and how to pass the parameters of contract objects fields.

thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are asking us to write some code for you. If you want you can go ahead and check out some of the following links and they should help you get started with this.

[Salesforce Trailhead - Apex Integration Services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/apex_integration_services)

[Using Force.com Integration APIs to Connect Your Applications](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-forcedotcom-integration-aps-connect-applications)